# Why v-on doen't work on Vue component while using it in outer template?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

### The situation

Let's say I have a component `BaseButton` which is just a simple wrapper arround a `<button>` element:

```
Vue.component('base-button', {
  template: `
    <button>
      <slot />
    </button>
  `
});
```

When using the button, I'll want to bind handler to a click event on this button:

```
<base-button @click="handler">
  Click me
</base-button>
```

[Pen with above code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrYLgM?editors=1111)

### The problem

The above solution doesn't work. The handler is not fired at all.

Can someone explain me why exactly? I'm guessing the handler is bound to the element, before it gets replaced with the component template, but it's just a guess - I can't find anything about it in vue.js docs. In addition to that [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Non-Prop-Attributes)
state:

> A non-prop attribute is an attribute that is passed to a component,
> but does not have a corresponding prop defined.
>
> While explicitly defined props are preferred for passing information
> to a child component, authors of component libraries can’t always
> foresee the contexts in which their components might be used. That’s
> why components can accept arbitrary attributes, which are added to the
> component’s root element.

`@click` (`v-on:click`) seems to me to be a non-prop attribute and according to the above text should get inherited. But it's not.

### Prop solution

I know I can declare a prop and pass the handler inside the component (code below). Then it works as expected.

The problem with this solution for me is that I don't have a fine grain control over how the handler is declared. What if in one usage of `BaseButton` I'd like to use on `@click`
some of the event modifiers Vue.js exposes (e.g. `.stop`, `.prevent`, `.capture`)? I'd have to use another prop (like `capture`) and use `v-if`, but it'd get the component template very messy. If I leave the handler in the template, where I use it, I can modify the event declaration as I want in a clean and flexible way.

```
Vue.component('base-button', {
  prop: {
    clickHandler: {
      type: Function,
      required: true
    }
  },
  template: `
    <button>
      <slot />
    </button>
  `
});

<base-button :click-handler="handler">
  Click me
</base-button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`v-on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) directive behaves differently when used on a normal / native DOM element or on a Vue custom element component, as stated in the API docs:

> When used on a normal element, it listens to **native DOM events** only. When used on a custom element component, it listens to **custom events** emitted on that child component.

In your case you apply it on your custom `<base-button>` element component, therefore it will listen only to custom event, i.e. ones that you explicitly `$emit` on this component instance.

Native `"click"` events bubbling phase from your underlying `<button>` will not trigger your `@click` listener…

…unless you use the `.native` modifier:

> `.native` - listen for a native event on the root element of component.

```js
Vue.component('base-button', {
  template: `
    <button>
      <slot />
    </button>
  `
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    handler(event) {
      console.log('submit from where the component was used');
      //console.log(event);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <base-button @click.native="handler">
    Click
  </base-button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that one :).